# Unable to trace Mysql in Packetbeat

Tags: mysql, monitoring, kibana, packetbeat

1. I'm using **packetbeat** for monitoring and I'm using ubuntu as an operating system.
2. I configured everything and the port for MySQL is 3306. I'm getting the dashboards in kibana, but if I start using MySQL I'm not getting anything in Packetbeat. It is unable to trace.

`[interfaces]
 #Select on which network interfaces to sniff. You can use the "any"
 # keyword to sniff on all connected interfaces.
 device = "any"`

`[protocols]
 #Configure which protocols to monitor and on which ports are they
 #running. You can disable a given protocol by commenting out its
 #configuration.`

`[protocols.http]
 ports = [80, 8080, 8000, 5000, 8002]`

`[protocols.mysql]
 ports = [3306]`

`[protocols.pgsql]
 ports = [5432]`

`#[protocols.redis]
 #ports = [6379]`

Comment: Configuration looks good. If you start packetbeat like this: `packetbeat -e -c /etc/packetbeat/packetbeat.conf -d "mysql,mysqldetailed,publish"` do you get any hints?

Comment: **This is the output im getting:**
`output_elasticsearch.go:58: INFO [ElasticsearchOutput] Using Elasticsearch http://175.41.145.234:9200'

'output_elasticsearch.go:59: INFO [ElasticsearchOutput] Using index pattern [packetbeat-]YYYY.MM.DD'

'output_elasticsearch.go:60: INFO [ElasticsearchOutput] Topology expires after 15s'

'publish.go:220: INFO Using Elasticsearch to store the topology'

'publish.go:185: DBG  Add topology entry for localhost: [10.150.147.210 fe80::2000:aff:fe96:93d2]'

'publish.go:185: DBG  Add topology entry for localhost: [10.150.147.210 fe80::2000:aff:fe96:93d2]`

Comment: I have to mention anything or configure anything for tracing mysql in conf file ?

Comment: Please help me.. I want to trace mysql into packetbeat... tell me what i have to configure.

Comment: You can also configure packetbeat to monitor mysqld process adding (or commenting out) following lines in the bottom of the file:
`procs:
  enabled: true
  monitored:
    - process: mysqld
      cmdline_grep: mysqld`

Comment: Moreover: if you are trying to monitor your mysql executing queries "locally"  you have to connect to mysql using not default socket, but TCP protocol, this way: `mysql -u user -p pwd --protocol=TCP`

Answer (score 1):

MySQL will attempt to connect via UNIX socket if using "localhost" (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connecting.html). But if you specify the IP (probably 127.0.0.1) it will connect via TCP instead, allowing Packetbeat to sniff that connection.